# Using one HDMI port as input with ability to switch outputs, possible?

Tags: hdmi

Iv got a question that im having a hard time figuring out if its even possible.

Does anyone know if its possible to use one of the HDMI ports on the Pi4 as an input, and have that signal passthrough to the output, however have the ability to programatically switch the output to the standard Raspberry Pi OS video output, and then back again to whatever signal is on the input?

We have a use case where we essentially need to programatically switch the signal on a display, between a Raspberry Pi and another display device, and im wondering if you can do that by using one of the HDMI ports on the Pi.

What's the verdict here?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pi's HDMI are output only.